Do all the geodesic equation of Schwarzschild metric should have the same unit?
I am plotting the rotation of Earth around the sun by using Schwarzschild Geodesic equations considering that $c$ is different than 1.
My question is: Should the geodesic equations have the same unit? or each one can have its one?

The Schwarzschild metric in spherical coordinates $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$ is
$$ds^2=\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)c^2dt^2
-\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2
-r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2 \theta\ d\phi^2).$$
Because the 4 coordinates $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$
have different units (time, length, dimensionless, dimensionless),
the 4 geodesic equations
$$\frac{d^2x^\mu}{ds^2}+\Gamma^\mu{}_{\alpha\beta}
\frac{dx^\alpha}{ds}\frac{dx^\beta}{ds}=0$$
for these coordinates will have different units as well:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^2 t}{ds^2}+...=0 \\ 
\frac{d^2 r}{ds^2}+...=0 \\
\frac{d^2 \theta}{ds^2}+...=0 \\
\frac{d^2 \phi}{ds^2}+...=0
\end{align}$$
This is very common in general relativity and no problem all.

Thanks for answering, even if it is indirectly. So we can say that No they shouldn't be the same, each one can have its unit.

@znp Correct. Each one can have its own unit.
